# My submit button in html template is not working in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I prepared an attendance register template in HTML.I have a HTML table and a submit button in the given HTML page.While clicking the submit button,i want to save the data in HTML table.But i can't.

Ist std.html

```
 {% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Attendance register</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 {
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: #f1f1c1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center><u>ATTENDANCE-REGISTER</u></center></h1><br>
<h2><center><i>Ist Standard</i></center></h2>
<h4>Class in-charge: Hema.B <br><br>
Date: June 2016 - March 2017</h4>


<form name="demo_form.asp" method="get">
<button type="submit" value="continue">Submit</button>
</form>

 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
{% endif %}

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
<th>Slno</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Attendance</th> 
    </tr>
  <tr>
<td>1</td>
    <td>Abijith</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="aNumber">
<button onclick="aFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="abFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="abNumber">
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>2</td>
    <td>Adithya</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="bNumber">
<button onclick="bFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="acFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="acNumber"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>3</td>
    <td>Bavana</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="cNumber">
<button onclick="cFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="adFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="adNumber"></td>

  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>4</td>
    <td>Bibin</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="dNumber">
<button onclick="dFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="aeFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="aeNumber"></td>

  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>5</td>
    <td>Devan</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="eNumber">
<button onclick="eFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="afFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="afNumber"></td>

  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>6</td>
    <td>Faizal</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="fNumber">
<button onclick="fFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="agFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="agNumber"></td>

  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>7</td>
    <td>Ganga</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="gNumber">
<button onclick="gFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="ahFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="ahNumber"></td>

  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>8</td>
    <td>Haris</td>

    <td><input type="number" id="hNumber">
<button onclick="hFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="aiFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="aiNumber"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>9</td>
    <td>Jamsina</td>

    <td><input type="number" id="iNumber">
<button onclick="iFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="ajFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="ajNumber"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>10</td>
    <td>Tara</td>

    <td><input type="number" id="jNumber">
<button onclick="jFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
<button onclick="akFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
<input type="number" id="akNumber"></td>
  </tr>


</table>
<br>

<body>
<script>



function aFunction() {
    document.getElementById("aNumber").stepUp();


}

function abFunction() {
    document.getElementById("abNumber").stepUp();
}
function bFunction() {
    document.getElementById("bNumber").stepUp();
}

function acFunction() {
    document.getElementById("acNumber").stepUp();
}
function cFunction() {
    document.getElementById("cNumber").stepUp();
}

function adFunction() {
    document.getElementById("adNumber").stepUp();
}
function dFunction() {
    document.getElementById("dNumber").stepUp();
}

function aeFunction() {
    document.getElementById("aeNumber").stepUp();
}
function eFunction() {
    document.getElementById("eNumber").stepUp();
}

function afFunction() {
    document.getElementById("afNumber").stepUp();
}
function fFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fNumber").stepUp();
}

function agFunction() {
    document.getElementById("agNumber").stepUp();
}
function gFunction() {
    document.getElementById("gNumber").stepUp();
}

function ahFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ahNumber").stepUp();
}
function hFunction() {
    document.getElementById("hNumber").stepUp();
}

function aiFunction() {
    document.getElementById("aiNumber").stepUp();
}
function iFunction() {
    document.getElementById("iNumber").stepUp();
}

function ajFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ajNumber").stepUp();
}
function jFunction() {
    document.getElementById("jNumber").stepUp();
}

function akFunction() {
    document.getElementById("akNumber").stepUp();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Views.py

```
def Ist_std(request):
    if 'save' in request.POST:
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)


            post.save()
            return redirect('blog/IInd_std.html', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/Ist_std.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^Ist_std/$', views.Ist_std, name='Ist_std'),
     ]
```

Comment: Hi, just going through some of my old answers and was wondering if you managed to sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be manually generating your form like that in your html. I can see that you have already had a look at django forms. May I propose the following:

```
<form name="demo_form.asp" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="continue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There are lot's of other [form rendering options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) as well. This approach will also ensure that the correct messages are displayed automatically when the form validation fails.

Also note that I have changed GET to POST. It's always better to use post for forms. I have added {% csrf_token %} remove this if you do not have the csrf middleware installed.

Comment: Good advice to use Django's form generation. In this case it is better to use POST since data will be modified, however, a query form should be GET since it is not mutating data. So it's not _always_ better to use POST for forms, but it often is.

Comment: Oops @hawke, i had added this in my answer 'Also note that I have changed GET to POST. It's always better to use post for forms' and then forgotten to change that in the code fragment :-) Thanks very much for pointing out

Comment: that wasn't my point, but glad it improved your answer. My point is that it is not _always_ the case that POST should be used for a form, e.g. when querying a database as opposed to updating one.

Answer (score 0):

In the template the `form` is closed before any `input` elements are defined, therefore the form will not contain any of the data entered as part of the table.

You can fix it by moving the `</form>` closing tag to somewhere after the end of the table.

Furthermore the `<input>` tags do not have `name` attributes, so none of the values entered in the input elements can be passed in the HTTP request. For example the first table row could be written as:

```
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Abijith</td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" id="aNumber" name="aNumber">
        <button onclick="aFunction()"><font color="green">Present</button>
        <button onclick="abFunction()"><font color="red">Absent</button>
        <input type="number" id="abNumber" name="abNumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

note that `name` attributes have been added to the input tags.

There might be other problems, but this is the one that stood out to me.

**Edit**

One other problem is that the view expects the data to be sent in a POST request, however, the form is using GET. Change the HTML form to use `method="post"`.

Comment: how can i add name attributes to the input tags?please reply

Comment: I can't able to enter input while the </form> closing tag is fix after the end of the table.

Comment: @Andrea: read my answer. It shows how to add name attributes. If you want to automate this look [e4c5's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38800824/21945). Re your second comment, add name attributes first, then it should work.

Comment: I tried to run the code with name attributes to input tags.but it's not working

Comment: @Andrea: see updated answer - you need to use POST in your form.